# Folder creation code not working in SharePoint environment

Tags: vba

I have a small piece of code called `Setup` that checks if a folder exists, creating it if it does not.

```
Sub Setup()

sFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

If Dir(sFilePath + "\Survey forms to go", vbDirectory) = "" Then
         
   MkDir sFilePath + "\Survey forms to go"
     
End If

If Dir(sFilePath + "\Survey forms to import", vbDirectory) = "" Then
         
   MkDir sFilePath + "\Survey forms to import"
     
End If

If Dir(sFilePath + "\Archived Survey forms", vbDirectory) = "" Then
         
   MkDir sFilePath + "\Archived Survey forms"
     
End If

End Sub
```

This works fine in a standard windows environment, however when I try to run this on Sharepoint I get a `Run time error 52, Bad File name or number` error.

I have tried the following without success:

```
Sub Setup()

sFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

If Dir(sFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "Survey forms to go", vbDirectory) = "" Then
   MkDir sFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "Survey forms to go"
     
End If

If Dir(sFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "Survey forms to import", vbDirectory) = "" Then
   MkDir sFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "Survey forms to import"
     
End If

If Dir(sFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "Archived Survey forms", vbDirectory) = "" Then
   MkDir sFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "Archived Survey forms"
     
End If

End Sub
```

How can I get this to run in a Sharepoint environment?

Comment: Not sure but I think the path separator is wrong. The backslash "\" is for windows systems but web uses the forward-slash `/`. Use `Application.PathSeparator` to be on the safe side for both.

Comment: thanks @KostasK. I still get the same message when I amend the code for Application.PathSeparator